# Как создать меню такое меню?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Дайте источники по созданию похожего меню (при нажатии на любой из пунктов, открывается целый блок) или хотя бы скажите как правильно его гуглить. Помимо этого , скажите как реализуется это меню на маленьком экране (конкретно интересует, как нижняя часть меню исчезает и появляется в блоке телефонного меню 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Меню называется аккордеон :). 1 картинка не трансформируется волшебным образом на телефонах. Просто создатели конкретно для меньших экранов адаптируют его, меняя css условия